# Unable to read a complete string while using scan option in java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    String s = "hello ";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int a;
     double b;
     String c;

     /* Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.*/

     a = scan.nextInt();
     b = scan.nextDouble();
     c= scan.nextLine();

     /* Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line. */

     System.out.println(i+a);
     /* Print the sum of the double variables on a new line. */
     System.out.println(b+d);
     /* Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line; 
        the 's' variable above should be printed first. */
     System.out.println(s+c);

     scan.close();
     }
}
```

when I give the input as
4
4.0
World! this is my first program in java

scan.nextLine() used in this code doesn't read the value of string.
I also tried using scan.next() which reads only till space (i.e only one word)

Comment: Don't know what you mean. Works fine for me. It prints out `8`, `8.0` and `hello World!`

Comment: what is your question? it's just too vague

Comment: Robby Cornelissen I want the output as 8, 8.0 and hello World! this is my first program in java not 8, 8.0 and hello World! my problem is that scan.next() is not reading entire string and scan.nextLine() is not reading a single word also.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to read multiword string, you could do this way:

```
String c = "";
String inputs[] = scan.nextLine().split(" ");

a = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
b = Double.parseDouble(inputs[1]);
for (int j = 2; j < inputs.length; j++) {
    c += " " + inputs[j];
}

System.out.println(i + a);
System.out.println(b + d);
System.out.println(s + c);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you

```
class solution{

    public static void main (String []rat){

    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    String s = "hello ";
    String c = "";

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputs[] = scn.nextLine().split(" ");

    Integer a = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
    Double b = Double.parseDouble(inputs[1]);
    for (int j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++)     
    {
        c += " " + inputs[j];
    }

    System.out.println(i + a);  
    System.out.println(b + d);
    System.out.println(s + c);  

    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what's the proposed improvement rather than asking the reader to compare both listings and try to understand what's the significance of the changes on their own.